Robot_localization's EKF module along with slam_toolbox causes jumpy robot odometry with encoder readings from diffDrive_arduino
I've been building a differential drive robot and learning ROS2-Humble for a few months now. Up until now I've succesfully used diffDrive_arduino for encoders, an ld19 lidar and slam_toolbox for mapping and navigation. It works but I do encounter wheel slipping, map getting destroyed when I crash etc.
Which is reason for which I tried using a mpu6050 imu and robot_localization pkg from ros2 to implement ekf filter and sensor fusion in order to get better and more robust odomentry.
However after doing so I've ended up with really weird error where the robot model/odom keeps jumping/teleporting after almost exactly 47-50 seconds.
After hours of trying to fix it myself here's all I've done:

I've switched off the imu sensor completely from the ekf.yaml file and by only using odom0 for the filter. I've figured out that even with proper encoder readings that work with slam_toolbox normally. If I use ekf filter with slam_toolbox on the odom computed by that reading I get erratic behaviour as mentioned above. (This roots out the imu as the cause of failure)
After manually trying out every most of combination inside the odom0_config setting (having only one on at a time while the rest is off and figuring out which is causing this disparency) I've found that the 6th boolean, corresponding to vx to be the culprit. When it is on, and only when it is on I get this erratic behaviour after some time.
This behaviour DOES NOT occur if I keep the robot as it is. Without moving it at all.
This behaviour ONLY occurs after minimum 47 seconds of moving the robot. Irrespective of any time inbetween where it was paused. It may have moved for 10 seconds with 15 seconds break inbetween but only after the 47-ish second mark does it start teleporting.
Finally without the ekf filter everything works fine. There is no issue with basic encoders as well. There are no erractic readings etc.

ekf.yaml (I deleted everything else in order to debug with default values.)
    ros__parameters:
        map_frame: map           
        odom_frame: odom
        base_link_frame: base_link
        world_frame: map           
        odom0: /diff_cont/odom
        odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
                       false, false, false,
                       true, false, false,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, false]
        odom0_differential: false`

controller.yaml
 controller_manager:
      ros__parameters:
        update_rate: 30
        use_sim_time: false

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

 diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:
    publish_rate: 50.0
    base_frame_id: base_link
    odom_frame_id: odom
    left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
    wheel_separation: 0.46
    wheel_radius: 0.090
    use_stamped_vel: false
    enable_odom_tf: false


As you can see in the above image. My tf connected to the base_link of my robot have been teleported to a different location (presumbly coz it is still in the same room). Yet the map and odom seem to stay back. Why does this happen? Is there a way I can rewrite my sensor fusion to make sure this never happens and I also get robust odom? But most importantly I wish to know WHY this occurs at all.

After extensive testing it seems I was wrong. This is not an issue with robot_localization package but rather seems to be an issue with the SLAM toolbox setup itself. Hence, I am going to post another post about this. Will link that post here.
